# Google Static maps how to get position from latitude and longitude

Tags: android, google-maps-static-api

I am downloading a static map image using Google's API like below
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-32.3917,115.867&zoom=7&size=640x480&scale=2&maptype=hybrid&key=YOUR_API_KEY

I know the center of map, zoom, scale and map dimension.
Now I want to calculate the position(x,y) from latitude and longitude like below
Point getPointFromLatLng(double lat, double lng)

Any help is so much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a static image location with a key. Then try to add  a location coordinate with zoom scale..

Your given link isn't working because you are not integrating API key with this.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?
center=-32.3917,115.867&zoom=7&size=640x480&scale=2&maptype=hybrid&key=*YOUR_API_KEY*
```

You need to paste your API key in last term

Refference :- https://staticmapmaker.com/google/

Comment: I already have the static image downloaded from the above URL using valid API_KEY, my question is how to calculate the x and y position for any given latitude and longitude.

Basically, we have an image with a centre which can be identified by a lat and lng. The image also has a zoom and  a width and height.
What we need is method that will convert a lat and lng (say for the users current location) and return the pixel x and y

Answer (score -2):

Try to add marker on given LatLng.

```
 @Override
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
      mMap = googleMap;
      // Add a marker and move the camera
      LatLng latlng = new LatLng(32.3917,115.867);
      mMap.addMarker(new 
         MarkerOptions().position(Gushi).title("Gushi,China"));
      mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Gushi));
   }
```

Comment: This is for Google Static Map which is an map image and not the actual map view object